# isnan function accepting dots

Tags: javascript, jquery

isnan() function also accepting .(dots). How to prevent them. This is sample code:

```
        var Price = $("#Price").val();            
        if (Price == "") {

            alert ("Required!");
        }
        else if (isNaN(Price)) {               

            $("#Price").val(Price);
            alert("Enter digits");

        }
```

I'm calling this JS code in KeyUp event of the Textbox.

Comment: its because this function is not trustworthy > This [function is broken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description). You may be interested in ECMAScript 6 [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) : [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) so use `Number.isNaN(testValue)`

Answer (score 3):

```
else if (!/^\d+$/.test(Price)) {
    // only digits
}
```

Comment: a cool tweak would be to to prevent numbers starting with digit `0` too

Comment: @ajax333221: it depends on the task. `00001` is a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value is number by

```
 function isNumber(obj) {
     return isFinite(obj) && !isNaN(parseFloat(obj));
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we prevent the element to be entered if the validation fails, in keyup event..

Comment: you can show warning message under the input or add a *error* class to input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
else if(price.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
//Valid number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var Price = "10.00";            
if (Price == "") {
 alert ("Required!");
 }
else if(Price.search(".") != -1)
{
   alert(" cannot insert dots!");
}
else if (isNaN(Price)) {            
 alert("Enter digits");    
 }
```

Here:http://jsfiddle.net/K8FUW/